# Query String: How to append the ID of a row of a newly inserted database row (PHP)?

Tags: query-string, row-number

OK, I can get the number of the last row created, as I do below.  Now, I want to append it to the URL? query string so I can use this particular record on the next page.
Here's the way I'm trying to do it, where the field iduserid is my primary key.  If I just insert it into a text field on the page it displays the correct number. (  note: LastRec is a record set that contains the iduserid field of the current row)

But it doesn't return anything in the query string. What's wrong?

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT iduserid FROM userinfo ORDER BY iduserid DESC LIMIT 1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
$USER_ID = mysql_fetch_field($result,0);
?>

<a href="cp-AccountInfo.php?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?>"iduserid="<?php echo $USER_ID ?>""><div class="OKbtn"></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean...

```
 <a href="cp-AccountInfo.php?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?>&iduserid=<?php echo $USER_ID ?>"><div class="OKbtn"></div></a>
```

In other words, remove the quotes from your Url string and append the iduserid parameter with an ampersand (&) prefix.

Comment: This looks like the solution, but for some reason, it makes the OK button disappear, so I can't test it.  Thanks, and I'll let you know as soon as I figure that out.

Comment: OK.  Got my button back.  This still doesn't do it. The result is empty.

Comment: Aha!  Got it, thanks to your pointers...I just need to echo a server behavior that's already written, ask for the row I'm working on.  Looks like this: 
 <div class="OKbtn"><a href="cp-AccountInfo.php?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?><?php echo $row_LastRec['iduserid']; ?>"></a></div>